# My custom function returns the wrong thing rather than compiled string in Python

Tags: python, python-module, nonetype

I am making the module called indeX. There is a variable `__version__` which is the newest version. I have function that outputs the update info depending on the argument `v`. I want this function to output the latest update info if the `v` is `'n'`. So, I have a ton of variables of type `_update_desc1_0` (of course, it is not always `1_0`). I have custom function `_versionTransform(v)` that transforms e.g. `float(1.3)` into `str(1_3)`. I want to transform `'_update_desc' + _versionTransform(__version__)` to e.g. `_update_desc1_4`, and then return it.

I tried to make some boring stuff with `compile()` and `exac()`, but it didn't work.

**Transformating function**

```py
def _versionTransform(v):
    if type(v) == float:
        v = str(v)
        result = v.replace('.', '_')
        return result
```

**Version function**

```py
def getUpdate(v):
    if v == 'new' or v == 'newest' or v == 'New' or v == 'Newest' or v == 'n' or v == 'NEW' or v == \
    'NEWEST' or v == 'N':
        trans1 = _versionTransform(__version__)
        trans2 = '_update_desc' + trans1
        return exec(trans2)
```

I wanted it to output the info about the latest version, but it returns either `'_update_desc1_3'` or `None`

Comment: Are you sure? The same code, with the same parameters gives me _update_desc1_4... have you checked if your __version__ parameter is not 1.3?

Comment: It is not what I meant :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I solved it. The problem is that I typed `return exec(trans2)` instead of `return eval(trans2)`